# Using vim on a server

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I am using vim on remote Linux server. I want to copy some data from my local machine and paste it in vim. How can I do that?
I have already tried Ctrl+Shift+V and p option, but it does not paste the text that was copied from the local machine.

Comment: what's your local system? have you X installed? here I can do with mouse selection and middle button.

Comment: vim itself, when running in non-GUI mode, doesn't have copy/paste commands. You'll need to use whatever copy/paste commands are available in your terminal emulator. You'll have to go into insert mode first. If you have `autoindent` set and the pasted input is indented, it might end up looking strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data can be pasted in the editor using shift+insert.

Answer (score 0):

This depends upon the software you are using to access the remote shell. If you are using putty, just a right click should be enough. Pls give the details if you are using some other way to connect to the remote server

Comment: I am using putty to connect to the remote shell. Right click works, if you want to paste anything to the terminal. However, once I open the vim editor, right click does not paste any data, it just shows --VISUAL-- at the bottom. Neither does Ctrl+Shift+V and p option work.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you in "insert mode" in Vim before you paste your text?. Else vim will try to interpret the characters that you paste as commands. p will work only if the data is copied by the vim itself.

Comment: Yes, I am in "insert mode" in Vim. The data is not copied by vim. The data is copied from an excel file from my local Windows machine which I want to paste in vim on the server.

Comment: Ok.. are you copying the record / cell from the XL? That may not be ascii... Or did you click into the cell and pick up the text?

Comment: I am copying multiple rows and columns from excel using Ctrl+C. The cells contain ASCII values.

Comment: The cells contain ASCII values.. but when you copy, Microsoft also pads the ASCII text with the information that this was part of an XLS record, the record/cell delimiters are also copied... - This informatino is not ASCII. The VIM editor gets confused with these non ascii characters... You can try the following - first paste everything into a notepad editor. Then copy from the notepad editor and paste into the VIM. That should work because notpad takes care of eliminating any formatting related information